# unable to update rails 5.2.3 to 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have updated my gemfile for rails 6 but everytime I bundle install I get the following error

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    default_value_for was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.2.0, < 6.0)

    rails (~> 6.0, >= 6.0.4) was resolved to 6.1.0.rc1, which depends on
      activerecord (= 6.1.0.rc1)
```

and here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://gems.ruby-china.com'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.4'

gem 'shirinji-rails'

gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'olive_branch'

gem 'health_check'

#gem 'auto-session-timeout'

gem 'pg'
gem 'redis'
gem 'oj'

gem 'virtus'
gem 'stringex', require: 'stringex_lite'
gem 'attribute_normalizer'
gem 'default_value_for'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'pagy', '< 4.0'

# https://iplocate.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/code-samples
gem 'iplocate', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'
# https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder
gem 'geocoder'

gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-cron'
gem 'sidekiq-failures'
gem 'sidekiq_alive'

gem 'rdiscount'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'rack-attack'

# FIXME: deprecated
gem 'inky-rb', require: 'inky'
gem 'premailer-rails'
# /deprecated

gem 'mimemagic'
gem 'jwt'

gem "slack-notifier"

gem 'linkedin-oauth2'
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'elasticsearch'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1'

gem 'pusher'

gem 'addressable'

gem 'active_model_serializers' # TODO: replace by jbuilder

gem 'rubocop'

## TODO: deprecate the 2 first ones in favour of typhoeus
gem 'rest-client', '~> 2.0.1'
gem 'faraday'
gem 'typhoeus'
## /TODO

## TODO: get rid of devise
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem 'omniauth'
## /TODO

## TODO: remove SSR
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'clipboard-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'rails_bootstrap_sortable'
gem 'bootstrap-tagsinput-rails'
gem 'haml'
gem 'tinymce-rails'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'lazyload-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'formvalidation-rails'
gem 'nprogress-rails'
gem 'kaminari-bootstrap'
gem 'simple_form'
## /TODO

gem 'has_scope' # TODO: remove

## TODO: remove when every image is migrated
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'mini_magick'
## /TODO

gem 'pg_search' # TODO: use an index instead
gem 'ruby-progressbar'
gem 'staccato'

# gem for payment processing
gem 'paypal-checkout-sdk'
gem 'pingpp'
gem 'rqrcode'

gem 'faker' # TODO: remove from seeds and move the gem to test

# Monitoring Tools
gem "sentry-ruby"
gem "sentry-rails"
gem "sentry-sidekiq"

group :development do
  gem "spring"
  gem 'thin'
end

group :development, :test do
  # gem 'parallel_tests'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 3.7.2'
  gem 'rspec-retry', '~> 0.6.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'timecop'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'puma', '< 6'
end
```

Comment: Try updating that gem too: `bundle update rails default_value_for `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you only updated the rails gem but other gems are still using old rails you need to update each of them which need to be updated.

**Without Testcases:**

The proper way to upgrade the rails app is to change the gem version and then run `bundle update (gem_name)` then try to run the rails app if all works fine then good but most probably you get an error because of another gem, you have to run again `bundle update (gem_name1, gem_name2, .... gem_name_n)` keep appending gem names at the end of this command.

after each time you run the command you have to check app runs fine if not then fix errors in your app otherwise you successfully upgraded.

**With Testcases:**

The above steps of upgrading remain the same but with test cases, you just get assisted at checking your app once you upgrade any gem run all test cases if they all pass everything is fine.